# Creating a simple backbone app

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to teach myself Backbone.js by converting my simple static web app to a one page Backbone app. My problem is I can't find a simple tutorial for my problem.

I have the following function:

```
function convert(ins) {
    var numbers = parseFloat(ins);
    //Test for NAN
    if(isNAN(numbers)){
        $("#output").html("Error");
    }else{
        var conver = (numbers * 12);
        $("#output").html(conver);
    }
}
```

Right now this function gets called when the user inputs data into a field. It updates the output div automatically.
I want to have lots of conversion "apps". And the convert function needs to update when a user visits the page. 
How should I go about making models for each of my pages? The only line I want to change in my convert function is:

```
var conver = (numbers * 12);
```

I am really new to backbone obviously, and this is the last problem I need solved before I can start re-working my sites code.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Your convert function? Or are you trying to get it to fire whenever a user enters data into a field? I don't see anything you posted here related to backbone.js.

Comment: I'm just trying to get help writing a model in backbone that will have the same result as the code in my question. I know my question is lacking but I have no idea how to accomplish this in backbone.

Comment: OK, in this case I don't know that you need a model, perhaps what you want is just a view. I'll try and post an example soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since from the code you posted it seems like all that is happening is some conversions based on some user interactions, it would seem that a plain [view](http://backbonejs.org/#View) without a backing model would suffice. If your conversion function depended on some specific data (for example some formulas that came from your server) then perhaps a [model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) would be warranted, but based on what you posted I don't really see the need.

For example say your markup was something like the following

```
  <div id="divConversionCalc">
    <label for="txtInputNum">Enter inches</label> <input type="number" id="txtInches" />
    <label>Feet</label> <div id="dvOutput"></div>

  </div>
```

You can declare a backbone.js view that would encapsulate your function like the following

```
    var ConversionView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#divConversionCalc',

        events: {
            "change #txtInches": "convert"
        },

        convert: function (e) {
            var numbers = parseFloat(this.$el.find('#txtInches').val());
            if (isNaN(numbers)) {
                this.$el.find("#dvOutput").html("Error");
            } else {
                var conver = (numbers * 12);
                this.$el.find("#dvOutput").html(conver);
            }

        }

    });

    $(function () {
        new ConversionView();
    });
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/otexot/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it looks like your problem is that `ins` is a string, and you can't multiply a string with a number in Javascript.  You'll probably be good to go if you change it to `numbers * 12` instead.

Comment: _"You can't multiply a string with a number in JavaScript"_ I must disagree. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/yPysD

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was just a typo when I was writing the code for this question. All of my code is working the way I want it. My reason for asking this question is to get help converting this code to backbone.js code. Thanks again for the quick response though.